# Remove padding from first and last elements in a row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's assume there is a website with fixed width. I need to place 3 boxes in it with some space (padding) between the boxes. But I don't need padding on the left and right side.

How can I get rid of it? When I set `padding-left` or `padding-right` to the corresponding boxes, the boxes don't have the same size (width/height) anymore.

Here is my code:

```css
.wrap {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width:33.3%;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
}

.box-inner {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap clearfix">
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all other answers seem to be correct, I would do it using flexbox since it gives you more flexibility on the layout. Flexbox has a special property for that called `justify-content` and the value you want to assign to it is `space-between`.

```
.wrap {  
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      justify-content:space-between;
      align-content:flex-start;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1024px;
      height: 800px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:calc(33.3% - 5px);
    margin-bottom:5px;
    height: 200px;
}

.box-inner {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kztceukL/2/)

Comment: Your answer may be correct in what your trying to do, but your jsfiddle does not give the result the OP was asking for.

Comment: @DirtyRedz do you mean the space on the top is missing? I've updated the fiddle

Comment: Yeah in his code snippet he hase padding on the top and left, but from my understanded wanted to have equal padding around all boxs, thus getting rid of the double padding on the intior sides of the boxs.

Comment: Thank you very much for this brilliant solution.

Comment: Glad it helped. Flexbox is truly a game changer in many ways!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following CSS:

```
.box {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+1) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This will hide padding from the first element and every 4th one. Since the padding is on the left, every element on the right side will not have right padding.

[Here's the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/buy1scmr/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use *:last-child* and *:first-child* or even perhaps *:nth-child* pseudo element for styling and use CSS *calc* function to make sure you subtract padding from percentage width.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to alter the box model (flexbox provides several options to solve this problem), here are two selector combinations:

*This works on a single line container. The number of items per row doesn't matter:*

```
.box + .box { padding-left: 10px }
```

Using the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), apply the padding to all `.box` elements immediately preceded by a `.box` element.

Hence, the first item will not have left padding, and the last item will not have space on the right.

```css
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;                 /* adjusted */
}

.box + .box { padding-left: 10px; }  /* new */

.box-inner {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

*This works on both single and multi-line containers, with three items per row:*

```
.box:not(:nth-child(3n+1)) { padding-left: 10px; }
```

Apply the padding to all elements except ([`:not`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation)) every fourth, starting with the first.

```css
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;                               /* adjusted */
}

.box:not(:nth-child(3n+1)) { padding-left: 10px; }  /* new */

.box-inner {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.box:nth-child` to give the middle box's no padding, and have no bottom padding on any of the box's.

```css
.wrap {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width:33.3%;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(2),
.box:nth-child(5) {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.box-inner {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrap clearfix">
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><div class="box-inner"></div></div>
 </div>
</body>
```